# CSS question align div to the right side and transform it on hover to span the entire container beginning from the right side

Tags: css, image, hover

I am trying to have a box with three tilted pictures ( via skew(15deg) that upon hover will overlap the other two and fill the container. The problem is making the right side picture being drawn from the top right corner and not the top left corner.

The first image works easily, the hover effect ( the hover effect increased the width of the div ) just expands the div and the picture transitions over the two pictures to the right.

The middle one works because I used

margin-left 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);

which somehow makes the img being drawn from center. Upon hover this expands nicely to the left and the right.

for the right most picture I can't get it done. I am unable to make the picture being drawn from the right top side.

Any ideas?

Thanks for help best regards

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
margin-left: 100%;
transform: translateX(-100%)
```

on the right most div which made the image "originate" from the right side and expand from the right to the left upon hover ( which increased the width of the container). ( as I wanted )